# Wget fail - Service UnavailableUnable to establish SSL connection

Tags: proxy, wget, squid

I wget Zabbix repo to install the Zabbix-agent service
but it fails like this

`root@monitor:~# wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-  release_5.4-1+ubuntu20.04_all.deb --2021-10-27 10:22:48--  https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-  release/zabbix-release_5.4-1+ubuntu20.04_all.deb Connecting to 10.36.76.98:3128... connected. Proxy tunneling failed: Service UnavailableUnable to establish SSL connection`

I was set connect to squid proxy in /etc/ewgetrc like this:

```
root@monitor:~# cat /etc/wgetrc |grep proxy
use_proxy = yes 
use_proxy = on
http_proxy= http://username:passwd@10.36.76.98:3128/
https_proxy= http://username:passwd@10.36.76.98:3128/
ftp_proxy = http://username:passwd@10.36.76.98:3128/
```

Then Type  command: wget fileurl  but got this:

```
root@monitor:~# wget fileurl
--2021-10-27 10:25:56--  http://fileurl/
Connecting to 10.36.76.98:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2021-10-27 10:25:56 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

anybody can help me fix this?

Comment: Resolved:   I just need to remove domain 'repo.zabbix.com'  in /etc/hosts file on the proxy server.